# Recovery GPT after shrinking partition with sfdisk

Tags: partitioning, mount, data-recovery, disk, gpt

A year ago, my HDD was available from Windows but not mountable from Ubuntu. I used some table repair tools on Ubuntu but it just corrupted the GUID table. I fixed the table with Partition Wizard on Windows and went with it, nothing changed except that the end position of the logical partition was greater than the number of disk's sectors (info from gparted and sfdisk output).

So, having this output of sfdisk and following this (mixed up GPT and MBR) [instruction](https://gparted.org/h2-fix-msdos-pt.php)

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 1.8 TiB, 2000397852160 bytes, 3907027055 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 9F126AEE-463C-394E-A817-2AD9C33C6946
Device      Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1  264192 3907028992 3906764800  1.8T Microsoft basic data
```

I altered the value of sdb1 size so that the number of the last sector is [maximum possible value given by sfdisk] = 3907027021 and rewrote it to /dev/sdb with sfdisk. After that ntfs partition is visible from Ubuntu and Windows but cannot be mounted.

Now I have the file from sfdisk with backup:

```
label: gpt
label-id: 9F126AEE-463C-394E-A817-2AD9C33C6946
device: /dev/sdb
unit: sectors
first-lba: 34
last-lba: 3907027021

/dev/sdb1 : start=      264192, size=  3906764800, type=EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7, uuid=B5CAA620-E5FD-3343-B7A6-135065D0AD95
```

But it can't be written to /dev/sdb by the same procedure
[sfdisk /dev/sdb < backup.txt]
because it doesn't permit to set the value of the end sector greater than the number of disk sectors:

```
/dev/sdb1: The last usable GPT sector is 3907027021, but 3907028991 is requested.
Failed to add #1 partition: Invalid argument
```

The version of sfdisk is 2.31.1. Info given by gpart:

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.3

Type device filename, or press  to exit: /dev/sdb
Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/sdb: 3907027055 sectors, 1.8 TiB
Model: ST2000DM001-9YN1
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/4096 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 9F126AEE-463C-394E-A817-2AD9C33C6946
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 3907027021
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 264158 sectors (129.0 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1          264192      3907027021   1.8 TiB     0700  

Command (? for help): v

No problems found. 264158 free sectors (129.0 MiB) available in 1
segments, the largest of which is 264158 (129.0 MiB) in size.
```

Is it possible to repair the GUID table using remained information?

Comment: Generally after any resize of a NTFS partition you have to run chkdsk from Windows on it to update it. And with chkdsk flag set Linux NTFS driver will not mount it to prevent further damage.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, in my case utility testdisk fixed partition properties automatically, now the hard drive is again visible from Windows at least.

P.S. It's also become available from Ubuntu after adding a few megabytes (number of overlapping blocks times size of a block should be acceptable) to the end of the last partition i.e. shrinking a bit by utility on Windows.